# Маска для мобильного номера?

Tags: vue.js

Добрый вечер дорогие разработчики
Как реализовать маску для номера телефона
Чтобы она оначинала с +380 и дальше юзер вводил номер телефона #########

Нужно чтобы он не мог удалить +380 и весь номер передавался в запрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      userNumber: '+7911',
    }
  },
  watch: {
    userNumber: function(newNumber) {
      if (newNumber.length < 5) {
        this.userNumber = '+7911';
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="tel" v-model="userNumber" maxlength="12">
  <div>{{userNumber}}</div>
</div>
```